# Getting an 8-bit LCD display interface to work

Tags: arm, lcd, interface, tft

I have a LCD which this controller is used with: [LCD Single Chip Driver](http://www.kosmodrom.com.ua/el/ILI9331DS.pdf).

I am trying to get it to work with an 8-bit interface, but in my kit I can't find the three pins that are mentioned in the datasheet IM [0-2].

Here are some descriptions: [2.8" TFT LCD](http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/2.8%22TFT_LCD).

and here is the socket description of the LCD kit that I have: 
[Socket description](http://kbiva.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/board3.png)

Now the current interface of the kit that's working is 16-bit.

That's the schematic of the kit: [Kit Schematic](http://kbiva.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/hy-stm32_schematic.pdf)

**2nd Question:**

If this is not possible, it's already connected to FSMC 16-bit, is it possible to just send 8-bit data to the data pins by shifting the data? Because I'm trying to get a large double buffer 140*200*2 bytes and that would eat the memory, so if I have an 8-bit interface would it take less memory buffer, so is it OK to just send 8-bit data to LCD even if the interface is 16-bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bits in the interface has no bearing on how much memory is required to store the image. For example with the 8 bit interface a 65,536 color pixel is transferred in two bytes, whereas the 16 bit interface only requires a single transfer - but in both cases the data is 16 bits per pixel.

You could store your image as 8 bits per pixel and translate it into 16 bits 'on the fly'. However encoding RGB in 8 bits only allows for 2~3 bits per channel (eg. 3 bits each of Red and Green, 2 bits of Blue), so color images will not be photographic quality. To improve image quality you could index the 8 bit pixel values into a 256 color palette, which only requires an extra 512 bytes of memory for 16 bit color.

Comment: How with 8bit interface a 65k is sent  ? it would be only 255 colors ?

Comment: Would you elaborate more about indexing the palette ? did you mean that make a table of palette 256 color and each color is 2 bytes ? and then send the 16bits ?

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color

Answer (score 1):

The link **2.8" TFT LCD** states that LCD part number is **HY-TFT280** which has **ILI9331** controller Inside. This LCD is interfaced with 16bit data interface with the help of **ILI9331** controller inside on TCON Board.If you want to make it 8-Bit interfaced then you have to open the LCD Module which will be having a TCON board, In that board you have to find out the IM [0-3] Pin and you have to make it Pull Up or Pull down for 8-Bit Mode as suggested in the datasheet (But I am not sure whether it will work on 8-Bit interface, since only these pins are not responsible for making a LCD to switch between 16 to 8 Bit or some other Data Bit interface).

IM [0-3] Pins belongs to controller **ILI9331** not to the LCD Connector so it is not shown in the 40 Pin connector schematic. Since these pins are not in the control of user.

Comment: What about the 2nd issue? is it possible to send 8bit to the 16bit interface and just don't care about the reset 8 bits? so that I can save memory ?

Comment: I Have an experience with 8 Bit RGB LCD. When the software member of our team tried to interfaced it with 6 Bit RGB then the colour appears on the Screen was different than the actual. For yellow we were getting Green and etc.Even you can also try it with 8-Bit Data interface. Since you have to modify only the code which is not going to add you any extra cost :-)